# Burninate the "custom-module" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, burninate-request

"Custom module" is, in Drupal jargon, a module that is developed for a specific website, and that is not generic enough to be generally used in other sites. An example of custom module is the [Drupal.org customizations](http://drupal.org/project/drupalorg) module, which contains code very specific for Drupal.org.

[custom-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-module) doesn't have any meaning because:

- A question tagged [custom-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-module) would not get a different answer, as the code used for a custom module is not different from the same code used from a module that is hosted on Drupal.org, and which is not a custom module.
- There isn't an expert of custom modules.

I have removed the tag from questions, but it gets periodically added to new questions.

Comment: +1 Totally agree with this, however the alternative for this tag would seem to be "modules", whose tag wiki would then becomes confusing: *"Topics related to existing modules"*. Obviously custom modules don't necessarily exist yet so perhaps that text could be changed to encourage people to use that instead?

Comment: There is no alternative because there is no need to use a tag to mark questions about custom modules, for the reason I reported here. [tag:modules] is for questions about existing modules, but I start thinking it's not a good tag too.

Comment: Hmmm I see your thinking, however if "modules" was not an allowed tag would we end up with a load of different tags, one for each contributed module name? And I suppose the question is, if we did is that really a problem or the way it should be?

Comment: The problem is when the tag gets overused, such when the tag is added because the question is about a module. If it would happen, then all the questions would be tagged [tag:modules], or [tag:themes] as questions on DA are generally about a theme, or a module. When a tag is used in most of the questions, it loses its function of classifying. Until that doesn't happen, it is not a problem. Still, I am wondering in which cases [tag:modules] is used, if not in the case the OP is asking a comparison between modules, or for a module that can be used for specific purposes.

Comment: I would agree with that, [custom-module] is somewhat pointless.  Questions about module comparisons, or what modules to use would be good for [modules].  Otherwise, I don't see a problem with people using a tag for a specific module (as we do with Views, Rules, CCK, etc)

Comment: @Laxman13 Definitely, although with 9586 modules currently listed on d.o that potentially means close to 10000 individual module tags. Obviously nowhere near that amount will actually get created in reality but I guess it bears thinking about

Comment: @Clive It is also true that there isn't the need of using a different tag for each existing module. Remember that tags used by a single questions are monthly deleted. I don't have problem with [tag:modules] being used with questions about existing modules, but I think it's a bad idea if the tag is used to generally mean "this question is about a module" such as in the case of a question about a custom module code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I didn't know about the monthly clear-out, ignore my comment its not really valid in that case.

Comment: The word 'custom' should be banished from Drupal altogether. :-)