# Burninate "Custom" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There already was a request to [Burninate the "custom-module" tag](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/717/16495) and now I see it's rebirth as [custom](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom).

> [custom-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-module) doesn't have any meaning because:
>
> - A question tagged custom-module would not get a different answer, as the code used for a custom module is not different from the same code used from a module that is hosted on Drupal.org, and which is not a custom module.
> - There isn't an expert of custom modules.

The same stands true for [custom](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom), and it's even worse, because of it's even wider scope.

Comment: It's gone......

Comment: is there any tag like "status-completed" to inform others, currently this question is hanging in the middle. @Clive

Comment: @Bala only moderators can add [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: yaa I know that, that's why I ping @Clive

Comment: @Clive it was used again today on two question. Maybe ban would make sense?